# How to convert String into number and sort it?

Tags: java, sorting

Could somebody tell me the way to break down problem. The requirement is display a menu with choice bubble sort, insertion sort. Allow user to input infinite number and sort those numbers base on their choice. I am lost. This is the code I have been working on. I am confused how to let user input a String and split them to int and sort them, and how can we output the result in toString().

```
public class IntegerArraySorting{
    private int[] integerArray;
    int sortingMethod;

    public IntegerArraySorting(String listNumber, int sortingMethod) {
        //StringTokenizer strToken = new StringTokenizer(listNumber, " ");
        for(int i = 0; i < listNumber.length(); i++){
            integerArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(listNumber);
        }
        switch(sortingMethod){
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Sorting method: BUBBLE SORT");
            //Integer.parseInt(listNumber).bubbleSort();
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong Input");
        }

    }

    public void insertionSort() {
        for (int i = 1; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int B = integerArray[i];
            while ((j > 0) && (integerArray[j - 1] > B)) {
                integerArray[j] = integerArray[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            integerArray[j] = B;
        }
    }// where array is an array with size = n

    public void bubbleSort() {
        int n = integerArray.length;
        for (int pass = 1; pass < n; pass++) { // count how many times
            // This neintegerArrayt loop becomes shorter and shorter
            for (int i = 0; i < n - pass; i++) {
                if (integerArray[i] > integerArray[i + 1]) {
                    // exchange elements
                    int temp = integerArray[i];
                    integerArray[i] = integerArray[i + 1];
                    integerArray[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }// where integerArray is an array with size = n

    public void selectionSort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < integerArray.length; j++) {
                if (integerArray[i] > integerArray[j]) {
                    // ...Exchange elements
                    int temp = integerArray[i];
                    integerArray[i] = integerArray[j];
                    integerArray[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }// where integerArray is an array with size = n

    public String toString(){
        String str = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++){
         str = str + Arrays.toString(integerArray);
        }
        return str;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am confused how to let user input a String and split them to int and sort them,

There are numerous ways to input something from the user and use that. The simplest is to use an input stream and pass it to a scanner instance as below

```
Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// since your sorting method is an int
int userChoice = inputScanner.nextInt();

// now just pass this to the method and you have your input problem solved, 
//Yes you will have to make an object of your class
classObject.IntegerArraySorting(yourList, userChoice)
```

> and how can we output the result in toString().

```
//just call the method and it will display your toString() implementation

classObject.toString()
```

Comment: don't forget to close `inputScanner` i.e `inputScanner.close()` afterwards...it will close the underlying stream i.e `System.in`, in this case.

Comment: Yes true about that @SufiyanGhori

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your code for you and added explanation where necessary, please have a look,

There are two classes, `IntegerArraySorting` and `Main`.

I have written the code for your sorting algorithm and getter/setter for your `int` array in `IntegerArraySorting` while I have created the instance of this class from `Main` class. I have also removed the constructor and created a new method called `selectAndStartSorting` for the input to select your sorting algorithm.

Answers to your questions,

> I am confused how to let user input a String and split them to int

You can use `split()` method of `String` class to split the string based on any regex expression and them Parse the resultant string array to `int` using `Integer.parseInt`.

> and how can we output the result in toString().

Once the `String` array is parsed into `int` array and sorted, you can use `Arrays.toString` method to convert that sorted `int` array back to `String`,
`Arrays.toString(int [])`.

See the following code,

here is `IntegerArraySorting` class,

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class IntegerArraySorting{

    private int[] integerArray;

    // Getters/setters for array,
    public int[] getArray(){
        return integerArray;
    }

    public void setArray(int [] inputArray){
        integerArray = inputArray;
    }


    // Method to select sorting algorithm
    public void selectAndStartSorting(int sortingMethod) {

        switch(sortingMethod){
        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Sorting method: BUBBLE SORT");
            bubbleSort();
            System.out.println("DONE");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Sorting method: INSERTION SORT");
            insertionSort();
            System.out.println("DONE");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Sorting method: SELECTION SORT");
            selectionSort();
            System.out.println("DONE");
            break;
        default:
           System.out.println("Wrong Input");
        }
    }

    public void insertionSort() {
        for (int i = 1; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int B = integerArray[i];
            while ((j > 0) && (integerArray[j - 1] > B)) {
                integerArray[j] = integerArray[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            integerArray[j] = B;
        }
    }


    public void bubbleSort() {
        int n = integerArray.length;
        for (int pass = 1; pass < n; pass++) { 
            for (int i = 0; i < n - pass; i++) {
                if (integerArray[i] > integerArray[i + 1]) {
                    // exchange elements
                    int temp = integerArray[i];
                    integerArray[i] = integerArray[i + 1];
                    integerArray[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void selectionSort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < integerArray.length; j++) {
                if (integerArray[i] > integerArray[j]) {
                    // ...Exchange elements
                    int temp = integerArray[i];
                    integerArray[i] = integerArray[j];
                    integerArray[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Converting sorted int array into String
    public String toString(int [] array){
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }
}
```

here is `Main` class,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter Numbers in this format 2,4,51,42,4?");

        // String input must be in this format 1,2,3,5,3,7,9 i.e sperated by commas,
        String str = input.next();

        // Split the input string on every "," and save the resulting array as a String. 
        String[] strArray = str.split(",");

        // Create new int array to later hold the numbers
        int[] numbers = new int[strArray.length];


        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            // Convert each number from String array into int and put it in numbers array
            numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
        }

        // Create instance of IntegerArraySorting class,
        IntegerArraySorting first = new IntegerArraySorting();

        // set the Array in IntegerArraySorting (integerArray) to our integer array (numbers) 
        first.setArray(numbers);

        // Take input for choosing Sorting algorithm
        System.out.println("Select Sorting Method: ");

        int sortingMethod = input.nextInt();

        // Start Sorting
        first.selectAndStartSorting(sortingMethod);

        // Close Scanner
        input.close();

        // Print Sorrted numbers,
        for (int s : first.getArray()) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

       // Printing sorted array as String
       System.out.println(first.toString(numbers));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer **BufferedReader Class**

Suppose Input is like this

```
1000 999 888 666 5555 333 777 4444 9999 ....................
```

Seperated By Space then use

```
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String [] inputBuffer =(br.readLine().split(" ");
```

Now You have All Input Values in **inputBuffer** Array  , Parse them in Long,Integer, Double etc in whichever data type you want

Example :

```
Integer.parseInt(inputBuffer[i]);
```

Lastly Apply *Sorting*

Answer (score 0):

```
Thank you all of you for sharing your experience. I was trying to fix my code base on your answer, but the requirement is to write a construct that accepts a number list(String) a and a sortMethod(int), so I come up with this code


        import java.util.Arrays;

    public class IntegerArraySorting{
        private int[] integerArray;
        int sortingMethod;

        public IntegerArraySo

rting(String listNumber, int method) {
        String[] temp = listNumber.split(" ");
        integerArray = new int[listNumber.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            integerArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(temp[i]);
        }
        sortingMethod = method;
    }

    public void arraySort() {
        switch (sortingMethod) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Sorting method: BUBBLE SORT");
            System.out.println("Original list of numbers: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {

                 System.out.print(" " + integerArray[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("\rSorted list: ");
            bubbleSort();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Wrong Input");
        }

    }

    public void insertionSort() {
        for (int i = 1; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
            int j = i;
            int B = integerArray[i];
            while ((j > 0) && (integerArray[j - 1] > B)) {
                integerArray[j] = integerArray[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            integerArray[j] = B;
        }
    }// where array is an array with size = n

    public void bubbleSort() {
        int n = integerArray.length;
        for (int pass = 1; pass < n; pass++) { // count how many times
            // This neintegerArrayt loop becomes shorter and shorter
            for (int i = 0; i < n - pass; i++) {
                if (integerArray[i] > integerArray[i + 1]) {
                    // exchange elements
                    int temp = integerArray[i];
                    integerArray[i] = integerArray[i + 1];
                    integerArray[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }// where integerArray is an array with size = n

    public void selectionSort() {
        for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < integerArray.length; j++) {
                if (integerArray[i] > integerArray[j]) {
                    // ...Exchange elements
                    int temp = integerArray[i];
                    integerArray[i] = integerArray[j];
                    integerArray[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }// where integerArray is an array with size = n

    public String toString() {
        arraySort();
        String str = Arrays.toString(integerArray);
        return str;
    }

}


and this is my main()





    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class SortingApplication {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String listNumber;
            int sortingMethod;

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("SortingApplication");
            System.out.println("\t1." + "  " + "Bubble Sort");
            System.out.println("\t2." + "  " + "Insertion Sort");
            System.out.println("\t3." + "  " + "Selection Sort");
            System.out.println("\t4." + "  " + "Exit");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Please enter a number list: ");
            listNumber = keyboard.nextLine();

            System.out.print("Please select a desired method (1), (2), (3), (4): ");
            sortingMethod = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println();

            IntegerArraySorting intarray = new IntegerArraySorting_Luong(listNumber, sortingMethod);
            System.out.println(intarray);
        }
    }


The format of the output suppose to be:

Sorting method: BUBBLE SORT
Original list of numbers: 34 2 15 33 17 8
Sorted list:  2 8 15 17 33 34

but when I run my code, I can't get my original and sorted list in the same line and I get many extra zero:
Please enter a number list: 34 2 15 33 17 8
Please select a desired method (1), (2), (3), (4): 1

Sorting method: BUBBLE SORT
Original list of numbers: 
 34 2 15 33 17 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Sorted list: 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 15, 17, 33, 34]
```